# how to chain javascript selectors

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i've selected the following Ids in angularjs and i want to set the css to diplay none. the following code works well

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('cont_' + i)).css({display: 'none' })
angular.element(document.getElementById('resize_' + i)).css({ display: 'none' })
```

is there a way to chain both selectors to i don't have to write

```
.css({display: 'none' })
```

twice?  i tried the following but it obviously does not work

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('cont_' + i)).
angular.element(document.getElementById('resize_' + i)).css({ display: 'none' })
```

also, i need them to be with separate id because i use them individually in other places.

any ideas,

thanx,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use document.querySelectorAll, thus:

```
angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('#cont_' + i, '#resize_' + i)).css({display: 'none' })
```

Comment: In fact, the .css () function is from angular.element

Answer (score 0):

Use css dynamic selectors. 
Just get a parent element and then write `div[id^=cont_]` and write css there.